# SSRS report case statement

Tags: reporting-services, case, ssrs-expression

I have a title in SSRS which takes data from a table and depending on the month I run the report the title changes to that month. Currently it changes from "month 1" all the way to "month 12"

I need to change the below code so if it is "month 1" it displays january etc

This is the current code for the title:

```
  =First(Fields!Month.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Revised code working for this month

```
 =switch(
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 4", "January",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 5", "February",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 6", "March",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 7", "April",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 8", "May",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 9", "June",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 10", "July",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 11", "August",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 12", "September",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 1", "October",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 2", "November",
 First(Fields!Month1.Value, "DataSet1")="month 3", "December"
 )
```

Comment: I've used the below code which works for this month but not sure what will happen at a later date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your report parameter is a date why not simply use

```
=format((Parameters!DTfr.Value), "MMMM")
```

If you report needs column headings for successive months such as for a financial summary by month you could use something like

```
=format((Parameters!DTfr.Value).AddMonths(1), "MMMM")
=format((Parameters!DTfr.Value).AddMonths(2), "MMMM") etc
```

For each column heading